# Does axclient.py exist for ROS2?

Tags: ros, action

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `axclient.py` documented [here](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/Calling%20Action%20Server%20without%20Action%20Client) is quite a handy tool for quick debugging and testing.  Does its equivalent exist for ROS2?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399476/does-axclient.py-exist-for-ros2?/) by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1083 on 2022-04-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turns out, a CLI tool already exists which was added in https://github.com/ros2/ros2cli/issues/202

Quoting the ticket

```
  ros2 action send_goal ACTION_NAME ACTION_TYPE GOAL_MESSAGE
  # For example:
  $ ros2 action send_goal /fibonacci example_interfaces/Fibonacci "order: 5"
  Sending goal...
  Goal accepted.
  Feedback:
      sequence: [0, 1, 1]
  Feedback:
      sequence: [0, 1, 1, 2]
  Feedback:
      sequence: [0, 1, 1, 2, 3]
  Feedback:
      sequence: [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
  Result:
      sequence: [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
```

---

Originally posted by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) with karma: 1083 on 2022-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2023-06-14**:
Just to be clear, `axclient.py` provides GUI, not CLI. I bet those who lands on this question are looking for `axclient`-equivalent (i.e. GUI), which I doubt exists in ros2 yet.